# Simplify a date comparison

Tags: python

I've got the following python code that does a date comparison for a list sort function (e.g.  `date_list.sort(cmp=dcmp)`.  I'm wondering if it's possibly to remove the cmp/if testing and make it a oneliner.

```
def dcmp(a, b):
    amm, add, ayy = [int(v) for v in a.split('/')]
    bmm, bdd, byy = [int(v) for v in b.split('/')]
    v = cmp(ayy, byy)
    if v != 0: return v
    v = cmp(amm, bmm)
    if v != 0: return v
    return cmp(add, bdd)
```

Update: Let me make it clear what I'm curious about is can you remove this block of code from the function:

```
    v = cmp(ayy, byy)
    if v != 0: return v
    v = cmp(amm, bmm)
    if v != 0: return v
    return cmp(add, bdd)
```

Comment: Why are the arguments strings to begin with? Python has a [`date`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects) type.

Comment: Because they're read from a file and look like '10/12/2011' and used as a dict keys.

Comment: I still think NullUserException has a point. You can easily turn those strings into datetime objects using [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). This would allow you to do comparisons and you can still use them as dict keys.

Comment: You can use `date` objects as keys as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, what I was looking for was to replace just this code (**ignore that it was dates**)

```
v = cmp(ayy, byy)
if v != 0: return v
v = cmp(amm, bmm)
if v != 0: return v
return cmp(add, bdd)
```

The correct answer is:

```
return cmp(ayy, byy) or cmp(amm, bmm) or cmp(add, bdd)
```

Which can also be written as:

```
return cmp((ayy,amm,add), (byy,bmm,bdd))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `key` instead of `cmp`. It is a lot easier to write a `key` function, and can be done in one line.

```
date_list.sort(key = lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

You will also need this import:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: Not to mention that using `key` is likely to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly cleaner to convert these values to actual dates (though maybe slower--you'd have to benchmark it if speed is that important):

```
def dcmp(a, b):
    from datetime.datetime import strptime
    return strptime(a,'%m/%d/%Y') > strptime(b,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of your months and days are zero-padded and your dates are in m/d/Y format like "01/01/2001", you could write:

```
def datekey(d):
    m, d, y = d.split('/')
    return (y, m, d)

datelist.sort(key=datekey)
```

If the numbers aren't always zero-padded, you could cast each number to an int for comparison purposes:

```
def datekey(d):
    m, d, y = d.split('/')
    return (int(y), int(m), int(d))

datelist.sort(key=datekey)
```

This is *way* faster than using `strptime` if all your dates are in such a simple format:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> print timeit.Timer("datelist.sort(key=datekey)",
...     setup="""\
... datelist = ['01/01/2001', '01/02/2001', '12/31/1999']
... def datekey(d):
...     m, d, y = d.split('/')
...     return (y, m, d)
... """).timeit()
3.3154168129

>>> print timeit.Timer("datelist.sort(key=datekey)",
...     setup="""\
... datelist = ['01/01/2001', '01/02/2001', '12/31/1999']
... def datekey(d):
...     m, d, y = d.split('/')
...     return (int(y), int(m), int(d))
... """).timeit()
11.1701700687

>>> print timeit.Timer("datelist.sort(key = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y'))",
...     setup="""\
... datelist = ['01/01/2001', '01/02/2001', '12/31/1999']
... import datetime
... """).timeit()
59.2817358971
```

`strptime` is hugely powerful, very important to know, and very slow in this use case.

Comment: -1 Benchmarks of incorrect code are futile. `datekey('12/31/1999')` produces `[1999, 31, 12]` **FAIL**

Comment: Aww, crud. Edited. No point in being a jerk about the FAIL, though.

Answer (score -1):

Forget the date conversions, you can do this as strings. Just rearrange them to the proper order.

```
amm, add, ayy = a.split('/')
bmm, bdd, byy = b.split('/')
return cmp(ayy+amm+add, byy+bmm+bdd)
```

I prefer to use the [ISO date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which puts things in the proper order for comparison: `YYYY-MM-DD`. It also has the advantage of not being misinterpreted on the other side of the ocean.

Comment: -1 Unlike the OP's code, this will **FAIL** if the days or months don't have leading zeroes.

Comment: @JohnMachin, fair criticism.  As I said, I prefer to use formats where the leading zeros are guaranteed. And thanks for explaining the downvote, I do appreciate it much better than the anonymous kind.

Comment: So true about the other side of the ocean. Classic fail: batch job rejects about 60% of dates of birth and dates of employment commencement in file supplied by new "other side" subsidiary. Rejects laboriously "corrected" and re-entered. No realisation (until much later) that another about 37% would have been stuffed up but not detected.